# How to seed multiple category data with the help of model in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
Category::create(
        ['title' => 'See & do explore','parent_id'=>0],
        ['title' => 'Attractions & Activities','parent_id'=>1],
        ['title' => 'Neighbourhoods','parent_id'=>1],
        ['title' => 'Tours','parent_id'=>1]);
```

I am trying with this way. When i am running seed command every time first value entered in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to create an array for categories and pass it into foreach loop

```
  foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
         Category::create($value);
    }
```